# Seaside show: and onAnswer: and why is everything wrapped in one extra WAAnswerHandler compared to the equivalent call:?

Tags: pharo, seaside

I have trouble understanding why these two pieces of code behave differently. ClientView has `[ self answer: true ]` or `[ self answer: false ]` if the user clicks 'Save' or 'Back' buttons respectively.

```
html anchor
    callback: [ 
                ( self call: ( ClientView new client: Client new ) )
                    ifTrue: [ self inform: 'Client added' ]
                    ifFalse: [ self inform: 'Client not added' ] ];
    with: 'Add a contact'.
```

The first works well producing:

```
WADelegation > WAAnswerHandler > ClientView
```

But this one is a problem:

```
html anchor
    callback: [ 
                view := ClientView new client: Client new.
                view
                    onAnswer: [ :answer | 
                        answer
                            ifTrue: [ self inform: 'Client added' ]
                            ifFalse: [ self inform: 'Client not added' ] ].
                self show: view ];
    with: 'Add a contact'.
```

I think the error is in the one below, I expect it to behave the same as the one above. It produces an extra WAAnswerHandler:

```
WADelegation > WAAnswerHandler > WAAnswerHandler > ClientView
```

Clicking 'Save' or 'Back' and 'Ok' in any of the informs never actually resumes the call on the original component, it just keeps displaying ClientView over and over.

Notice the one below uses `show:` and a prefined `onAnswer: block` on the view while the one above uses `call:`

Latest test works with:

```
html anchor
    callback: [ view := ClientView new client: Client new.
        self
            show: view
            onAnswer: [ :answer | 
                answer
                    ifTrue: [ self inform: 'Client added' ]
                    ifFalse: [ self inform: 'Client not added' ] ] ];
    with: 'Add a contact'.
```

or the equivalent

```
html anchor
        callback: [ self
                show: (ClientView new client: Client new)
                onAnswer: [ :answer | 
                    answer
                        ifTrue: [ self inform: 'Client added' ]
                        ifFalse: [ self inform: 'Client not added' ] ] ];
        with: 'Add a contact'.
```

NB. Essentially they are the last two code samples on this page http://book.seaside.st/book/components/calling/show-answer , only they aren't equivalent.

Comment: Have you read through http://book.seaside.st/book/components/calling/show-answer ? Can you explain and rephrase the question what you were expecting and what does not behave as expected?

Comment: @JohanB edited the question the two methods produce different results, the second being wraped in an extra WAAnswerHandler which effectively means you never can get back to the original component. Also in the question i mixed the examples around, now they are ok.